# Codeigniter controller functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

In my controller i have a view for registering new members.

Instead of making a whole new function for that such as,

```
public function show_registration(){
$this->load->view('registration');
}

public function validate_registration(){

}
```

Instead of doing the one above where i make a function to show the view then a new one to receive the data from the view, i made it like this.

```
public function registration(){
if(array_key_exists('submit',$_POST)){
/////if exist process the data here
}else
$this->load->view('registration');
}
```

The above if statement, checks if ever there was data submitted to the function if not then it would show the view else it will process the data.

It seems like more of an ideal way right? then i thought, what if this could cause problems?

Is there any chance or possibility this might ruin my project? I am starting right now, and i just want insights whether i should pursue my current way or i should just create a separate one for showing the view.

**EDIT: I just realized, this does not necessarily check all submitted data, but only data submitted by the button of the name 'submit', so as long as i keep the name of the submit button for every form unique as possible then i should be fine.

sample: form for registration, button name should be registration.**

Comment: you should use codeigniter form validation class, it is exactly what you need: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: I'd start by using `input` class since it has some useful filters and check out validation class for forms as well. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html ; http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: How should i use it? my point is to check if there was data submitted. I dont know how validation comes into play with this.

Comment: $this->form_validation->run() is done for that, if it's true, the form was submited

Comment: But thats too ambigous right?

i mean, if there was data submitted by another form?

That was my concern. although i dont know how it would occur, i just am making sure

Comment: @user3432132 `form_validation->run()` returns `false` when no data found in `$_POST`, And you can set rules for each data to validate and it will set error you can print those errors using this `valid_errors()`. I don't think there will be a concurrent form submit.

Comment: Still though, since the one im currently using is more specific since it points to what submit button the data came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can do with codeigniter

```
class Form extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does validatio run do exactly?

My main idea of it is to run the set rules i declared, or am i wrong?

Comment: please read the documentation here:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: It would be nice if you could stop sending me links to the documentation, i am currently on it. 

As i said on my post, i am asking for insights.

Answer (score -1):

Using Codeigniter you have to follow [codeigniter-form-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328719/codeigniter-form-validation) for loading a view or submitting your form for more information visit this [Codeigniter  form_validation library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.